# Switching off visibility of installed google apps marketplace app result in authorization failure in OAuth version 2

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

In the older apps marketplace, a domain admin could switch off app visibility from the apps admin panel and the authentication/authorization to a 3rd party app still kept working.

After the OAuth2 migration, I see that switching off app visiblity to "Off", stops the 3rd party app to refresh the access tokens (for offline access) and returns access denied. Is this an issue or is it supposed to work this way ? We are using Service account to access.

I do not want the installed 3rd party app icon to appear in Gmail universal navaigation for all the domain users and still the autorization ( and offline acccess) to keep working.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this change as well.  We have had to create multiple marketplace listings to get around this.

1 Listing for users that want the contextual gadget

1 Listing for those users that want the universal navigation

1 Listing for those users that want no universal navigation

You can turn off the universal navigation in the Marketplace Setup console by unchecking "Enable Universal Navigation extension"